# Prevent php script from timeout while processing thousands of records

Tags: php

I have a php script that checks if email address is still valid with SMTP HELO, we mark that address as valid in separate CSV and then sends newest offer we have (if user of course requested that). Addresses are taken from txt file where they are stashed line after line.

So flow of the script is like that: open txt file, grab all lines and place it in array, iterate through each record in array & send SMTP HELO, mark as valid/invalid in separate CSV, send email to valid.

We have often 2.000+ records in each source txt file. Unfortunately, I have never passed 400th record as my CloudFlare or nginx gives my timeout.

I have tried following setup inside my php script:

```
set_time_limit(0);                   // ignore php timeout
ignore_user_abort(true);             // keep on going even if user pulls the plug*
while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean(); // remove output buffers
ob_implicit_flush(true);             // output stuff directly
```

and some various "hacky" async approaches, but result is always the same.

I thought about "slicing" my input data to safe-size inputs and proceeding one file after another with page reload in the meantime, but I have no idea is it approach worth pursuing or I should look for something else?

Comment: perhaps there's an issue with the file it's reading (i.e., the iteration it's timing out on). Like a white space or special character. Assuming the previous iterations are functioning as expected but, if your sending everything in batches it wouldn't be seen until after the file's been parsed. try reviewing the file or use a delimiter before tossing it into an array.

Comment: Sounds like this is a server settings issue, so your local settings may not have much of an affect.  If that is the case, then you will want to batch process your data, which is probably best practice for code portability reasons. I fixed it with [Gearman](https://gearman.org) but [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) may be a better fit.